# How to make two bar phrases in two columns per page

Tags: lilypond

In the style of "Stick Control for the Snare Drummer" I'd like to set my page in two columns having 12 2-bar phrases in each. I have [this attempt](https://gist.github.com/bugthunk/81f35a70a0fe434098f51a32f38dbfde) which is nearly exactly what I want, except I would like the 2-bar phrases to line up. This could be achieved by e.g. making the spaces between each consecutive 2-bar phrase equal but all my attempts by following the manual have failed so far - presumably because everything is wrapped in `markup`. The approach with `markup` was the only approach I found to create multiple columns, which I found [here](https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=1013)

Is there any other approach that could be used, or is there some variable I could poke in order to make the systems vertically equidistant?

[image: Picture displaying the misalignment]

Comment: Worst case it seems I can manually add `\fill-line { \override #'(baseline-skip . $MAGIC_NUMBER)` and correct them and actually get a passable result. I'd rather not go through all files manually, though... –

Comment: Indeed, "Vertical spacing of a \score inside a markup object is controlled by baseline-skip. Any \paper settings are ignored." From http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/formatting-text#music-notation-inside-markup

Answer (score 4):

I think `\table` solves your problem.

See [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/text-markup-list-commands) for more.

An example:

```
\version "2.22.0"

\markup \fill-line {
    \column
    \override #'(padding . 20)
    \override #'(baseline-skip . 12)
    \table #'(0 0) {
        \score {
            \new Staff \relative c' { c2 d e f }
            \layout { }
        }
        
        \score {
            \new Staff \relative c' { d2 e f g }
            \layout { }
        }
        
        %-----
        
        \score {
            \new Staff \relative c' { e2 f g a }
            \layout { }
        }
        
        \score {
            \new Staff \relative c' { f2 g a b }
            \layout { }
        }
    }
}
```